# Candle flame effect

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, effects

I want to develop a candle flame with Silverlight 4.

I've found this [example](http://designleon.com/temp/candle/candleflame.html) made with Flash. The source code is [here](http://designleon.com/temp/candle/candleFlame.fla).

I have Adobe Flash Builder, but I can't open it.

Do you know how can I open it? This code will be very useful to start.

By the way, there is another example [here](http://www.greatandlittle.com/studios/index.php?post/2011/08/17/The-Peter-Joel-Candle-Flame-Effect-in-AS3), that should be useful.

Any clue? (I know this question is very short, but I don't have more details to put and I don't know how to start developing this effect. Sorry).

Comment: I don't program in Flash at all, but I'd be surprised if Flash Builder allowed you to open someone else's finished product to have a sticky-beak.

Comment: Why would people downvote this? It's such an interesting question!

Comment: People have voted and have not said way: we'll learn a lot from such behaviour.

Comment: not sure if this would help? http://pixelplastic.de/2009/08/04/firewithwriteablebitmap.aspx

Answer (score -3):

First off, question length does not predicate question value.  The problem with your question is that it isn't focused.  As for answering your exact question, you can't open that file with Flash Builder because it was built with the Flash CS, which is a mix of art tools and dev tools (neither of which are very good).  Flash Builder is a only developer tool.
But opening that file in flash isn't going to get you all that close to your goal of a candle flame in silver light unless you know a bit about silver light to start .

Comment: what's wrong with my answer here?  The down votes don't really tell me.